# base64 decode dashboard content for Grafana to use or upload plain text dashboard file to Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am creating Grafana pod directly with deployment (not using Grafana helm/operator). I have some dashboards that I want to upload, when I use configmap with jsonContent in it, data in it is causing issues for helme, I tried to read it as a file using .Files.Get , same issue.

So I have base64 encoded it

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: grafana-dashboard
    namespace: monitoring
data:
     default:
          {{ .Files.Get “files/dashboard.json”  | base64enc}}
```

I have mounted this to volume in deployment definition

```
volumeMounts:
 - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
        name: grafana-dashboard
volumes:
  - name: grafana-dashboard
       configMap:
            name: grafana-dashboard
```

Challenge is that base64 encoded dashboard file is available in /var/lib/grafana/dashboards hence dashboard  is not coming up.

How can I get plain text copied ? Is there any other better solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use `tpl` for this and instead of using `base64enc` use `indent 2` for proper indentation. Also make sure to add `|` after the `default:` key to indicate a multiline scalar block and to preserve the line breaks.

Comment: Even tpl is replacing the json in configMap and that is causing the issue...

Comment: After some research I found that json dashboard has {{}} go lang tags like the one shown ... as a result Helm is trying to substitute that ...  when I use tpl, or toJson , it is escape sequencing doublequotes ..  I get output but that doesn't help in Grafana to finally display dashboard.  What can I do to avoid conflict ?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, maybe use `tpl` along with `quote` to escape the content properly. I'm not quite sure what the result will be. I guess you could go with something like this: `default: |-
{{- tpl (.Files.Get "files/dashboard.json" | quote) . | indent 2 }}
`

Comment: Thanks @Keygun2k1, your solution helped. If I try to escape , those escape charecters are not properly understood by Grafana. , I have got it worked with {{- tpl (.Files.Get "files/dashboard.json" ) . | nindent 4 }}, I also have used a variable in Value to replace those golang tags in json file...  like   replace_string="{{ __name_ _ }} [{{host_id}}]" ...

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you and that you've managed to find a solution using my example. Good luck on your project and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [InitContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in the Grafana pod.

That container would simply read your files from the same `grafana-dashboard` volume mount and decode the base64 content before Grafana will start.